# div alignment is not coming properly

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want - box to come exactly below + box as shown in the attached image

[image]

I have tried this code given below but does not work. Can someone tell me what changes I need to make in the css. This is part of reactjs application.

```
<div style={{width:"20%",float:"left"}}>
                   <input type="text" style={{width:"50px",height:"60px",marginLeft:"20px",marginTop:"20px",float:"left"}}/>
                   <div style={{fontSize:"25px",fontWeight:"bold", width:"30px",float:"left",border:"1px solid #eee", marginTop:"20px",marginLeft:"5px",textAlign:"center"}}><a href="#" style={{textDecoration:"none"}}>+</a></div>
                   <div style={{fontSize:"25px",fontWeight:"bold", width:"30px",float:"left",border:"1px solid #eee", marginTop:"20px",marginLeft:"5px",textAlign:"center"}}><a href="#" style={{textDecoration:"none"}}>-</a></div>
                 </div>
```

Comment: don't use inline css - it's bad practice that leads to hard to maintain code - also your css attribute names are wrong, not camelCase but hypenated-attributes (so `fontSize` should be `font-size`)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, When using it in JSX, the css properties need to be written in camelCase. so `font-size` is indeed used as `fontSize`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri really? that's just .. weird. also seems really pointless when you could save 2 chars per line using `style="font-size: my-val"` - but maybe there's other benefits to JSX that I'm not aware of :) either way will adjust my previous comment - can't (left too long :/)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, You can check the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style if you want to know more about it, however you are right about  avoiding  inline styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `+/-` boxes in a `div` and use `display: flex` with `flex-direction: column` styles on the wrapper `div` like

```
<div style={{width:"20%",float:"left"}}>
    <input type="text" style={{width:"50px",height:"60px",marginLeft:"20px",marginTop:"20px",float:"left"}}/>
    <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
        <div style={{fontSize:"25px",fontWeight:"bold", width:"30px",float:"left",border:"1px solid #eee", marginTop:"20px",marginLeft:"5px",textAlign:"center"}}><a href="#" style={{textDecoration:"none"}}>+</a></div>
        <div style={{fontSize:"25px",fontWeight:"bold", width:"30px",float:"left",border:"1px solid #eee", marginTop:"20px",marginLeft:"5px",textAlign:"center"}}><a href="#" style={{textDecoration:"none"}}>-</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapp em in div with flex

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>

</div>
```